# Using Fb.ui feed method not showing message nor user_prompt_message at all using default messages

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, message

Hi I am new to facebook development, and would like to post a feed using this code below, but the message nor the user_message_prompt do not appear in the text box. Do I need to set something in my application to allow this. All I get is default messages.

I tried the 2 methods below, and both of them do not show the message nor user_message_prompt message.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>

        FB.init({ appId: "174009502722096", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

        function postToFeed() {

        var publish = {
        method: 'feed',
        message: 'Martin Okello presents share',
        caption: 'Visit MartinLayooinc',
        description: (
        'Martin Okello, aka the medallion presents his application'
        ),
        link: 'http://www.martinlayooinc.co.uk',
        picture: 'http://www.martinlayooinc.co.uk/topImages/bigMedallion.jpg',
        user_message_prompt: 'Share MartinLayooinc Software with friends!'
       };

       FB.ui(publish, 
       function(response)
       {
       alert('MartinLayooInc has been posted!!')
       });

       function callback(response) {
       document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
       }

       FB.ui(obj, callback);

       }

</script>
    <!--from here-->
    <div id="fb-root">
        <p>
            <a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'><img src="topImages/facebook_button.png" style="height:20px; width:80px;" />
            </a>
        </p>
        <p id='msg'>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '174009502722096', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

        /* All the events registered */
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
            // do something with response
            login();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
            // do something with response
            logout();
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                login();
            }
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe they are both deprecated. The message parameter is now ignored and I didn't see the other parameter in the documentation. Apparently, Facebook wants users to put their own message into the text field rather than be forced or prompted. Check out the main info page for it here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

and the detailed page here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Scroll to the bottom and you'll see the supported parameters. Hopefully it's not a game changer for you.

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like this

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({
appId: '{YOUR APP ID}',
xfbml: true,
version: 'v2.1'
});
};
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {
return;
}
js = d.createElement(s);
js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function share_prompt() {
FB.ui({
method: 'feed',
name: 'Your App Name',
link: 'https://example.com',
picture: 'http://example.com/img/fbicon.jpg',
caption: 'Your Caption here',
description: 'some sort of your own description',
message: 'Your Message goes here mate'
 });
 }
```

Then call the function like below;

```
<div><a href="#" onclick="share_prompt()">Click to open your dialog</a>      </div>
```